# Weird behavior while printing character array in file in C

Tags: c++

I saw some weird behavior with my C++ function whose work is to simply put 'n' ones(1).

```
char *getSpaces(int n) {

    char s[50];
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        s[i] = '1';
    }

    s[i] = 0;
    return s;
}
```

When I do `fout<< getSpaces(20)`, I get following output in the file :-

```
1111111111SOME_WEIRD_CHARACTERS_HERE
```

Can anybody explain this?

P.S. I am using codeblocks IDE on windows platform.

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable. That ceases to exist when the function returns. Let me look for a duplicate.

Comment: Also, `getSpaces(100)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more thing which I noticed is that when I tried allocating memory dynamically of size n(using new operator) within the function, it worked fine. Is it because I didn't delete dynamically allocated memory before exiting function?